# jquery - select class elements and add to array

Tags: jquery, class, select

I want to select all the elements with the class "play" and add them into array "esArreglo".

html file:

```
<td id="b1" class></td>
<td id="b2" class></td>
<td id="b3" class="play"></td>
<td id="b4" class="play"></td>
```

code:

```
$('td.play').each(function() {
    notas.push(this.id)};

var esArreglo = notas.join(',');
```

How can I fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem? You code looks fine except for a stray missing `)` at the end before your `var esArreglo` statement, ie `});` right after the `notas.push...`. And move the `;` to after the `.push()` part.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [jQuery.map](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
var esArreglo = $('td.play').map(function() {
  return this.id;
}).get().join(',');
```

Comment: `$.fn.map()`, which you're using in your answer, behaves a little differently than `$.map()`. It returns a jQuery object, not an array, so you have to call `get()` before `join()` for your code to work.

Answer (score 0):

May coz be you are missing the `);` in `.each`

```
$('td.play').each(function() {
    notas.push(this.id)
});

var esArreglo = notas.join(',');
```